# Get a substring truncated in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, char

Question for everyone... I have some values I've inserted into a table as I try to play around with string functions. What I'm trying to do is remove the end of the string and keep everything before it:

```
CREATE TABLE #BrokerNameT
  (
     BrokerName VARCHAR(100)
  )

INSERT INTO #BrokerNameT
            (BrokerName)
VALUES      ('Peter Pan Co Cash'),
            ('Batman Co Cash'),
            ('Spiderman Algo'),
            ('Spiderman Cash')
```

Here what I'm looking to is simply return: 'Peter Pan Co', 'Batman Co', and 'Spiderman'

Is it possible to search for the first space from the **end of a string?**
If i was able to do that, couldn't I just then keep everything before the first space?

Any idea how I'd go about doing this?

Could I use two reverses to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Reverse the string, then find the position of the first space, then you know how far form the end the last space is.

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(
    BrokerName,
    1,
    LEN(BrokerName) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(BrokerName))
  )
FROM
  #BrokerNameT
```

Comment: Isn't it stupid that SQL Server hasn't moved ahead to do something as simple as this and regex for example?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query to do it:

```
select *,
       left(BrokerName, len(BrokerName) - charindex(' ', reverse(BrokerName))
           ) as AllButLast
from BrokerNameT
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf015/3) is a SQLFiddle to demonstrate it.